# double free or corruption (top) after resetting log file

Tags: c, memory-corruption

I am writing away information in a system.log file. Before writing I check if the file hasn't reached it's limit. Out of nowhere the program crashes. Sometimes after 2 minutes, sometimes after an hour.

```
*** glibc detected *** ./anemometer: double free or corruption (top): 0x0001e3e0 ***
======= Backtrace: ========= resource busy
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7049c)[0x4025b49c]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x98)[0x40260db8]
/lib/libc.so.6(fclose+0x1b8)[0x40249c3c]
./anemometer[0xdc5c]
./anemometer[0xd104]
/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x5a90)[0x401bda90]
/lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x88)[0x402c3fb8]
======= Memory map: ========
00008000-00013000 r-xp 00000000 1f:03 500        /home/anemometer
0001a000-0001b000 rwxp 0000a000 1f:03 500        /home/anemometer
0001b000-0003d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
40022000-40023000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40029000-4002a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
4003f000-40040000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40040000-40053000 r-xp 00000000 01:00 2015       /lib/owasys/libRTU_Module.so.0.0.1
40053000-4005b000 ---p 00013000 01:00 2015       /lib/owasys/libRTU_Module.so.0.0.1
4005b000-4005c000 rwxp 00013000 01:00 2015       /lib/owasys/libRTU_Module.so.0.0.1
4007c000-4007d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
```

Below the write-away code is given. Ive seen solutions where they say fclose() might be called twice, or free() is used incorrectly. Both of these aren't the case here, right?

```
float systemLogMB = 3
void writeSystemLog(char log_print[])
{
    int fileS = checkFileSize("system.log");
    if (fileS < systemLogMB*1024*1024)
    {
        system_log = fopen("system.log", "a+");
        fprintf(system_log, "\n %s %s:      ", __DATE__ , __TIME__);
        fprintf(system_log, log_print);
        fclose(system_log);
    }
    else
    {
        system_log = fopen("system.log", "w");
        fprintf(system_log, "RESETTING SYSTEM LOG REACHED MAX");
        fprintf(system_log, "\n %s %s:      ", __DATE__ , __TIME__);
        fprintf(system_log, log_print);
        fclose(system_log);
    }    
}

int checkFileSize(const char* addr)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(addr, "a+");
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int fileSize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    fclose(fp);
    return fileSize;
}
```

Comment: Do you use multi-threading ? It can be a race condition.

Comment: Yes, I do. I am working with multiple sockets to stream data to multiple clients. Whenever Ive sent 200 packages to a client, I write: 
``sprintf(writeLog,"Socket %i sent %.2f kb in %i packets", newSocket, kb, counter); writeSystemLog(writeLog);``

Comment: your BT says `fclose` is the one that is causing this crash. did you try to compile with `-g` flag to get any additional info from the dump?

Comment: @SamDaniel I am running it now with a ``-g`` flag. However, the software runs on a seperate linux mini-computer. I am not sure how much extra information I will retrieve.

Comment: `system_log` seems to be global. That could be deadly if you're multithreading. Imagine: 1:) thread 1 opens, 2.) thead 2 opens overwriting `system_log`, 3:) both threads write, 4:) thread 1 closes, 5:)thread 2 closes using the same file pointer

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt ``system_log`` is a local variable, right? I designate it when opening the file. However, the file ``system.log``  is a global file. I assume, following Jona, that the problem originates, much as you describe, when the file is double opened. How would I fix this?

Comment: I see no definition like `FILE *system_log;` in the code you've posted so I had to assume it's global

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt https://i.imgur.com/MuSge4g.png My bad :)

Comment: So it's declared outside `writeSystemLog()` ?. Then it's no local variable and what I've said might happen. Just use a local `FILE *` like you do in `checkFileSize()`

Comment: Only with [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) every thread will have it's own

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt It has been runnning for a few hours now. I assume the problem is fixed! Thank you!